# A quick question about css modules and if I always need className

Tags: html, css, reactjs, css-modules

So I just encountered a bug that stumped me for a little bit using css modules in my react(cra) application and I was only able to solve it by looking at the style tags that get injected in the head from css modules

my problem is in my styles.module.css file I had some generic selectors like so

```css
p {
 ...
}
```

and that worked fine until I used a p element in another component and thoes same styles applied to it. is there anyway to get around this or do I need to just give all my elements a className={styles.whatever}

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question. If you have a global css which applies a style to all `<p>`-elements, it is only natural that your `<p>` elements inside your different components get the style as well. I am not sure what you mean is the bug?

Comment: maybe I did not explain good enough. I had a bug that I solved where p {} in my styles.module.css file was effecting my other components and I was wondering if I could have generic selectors like that scoped aswell or if I need to just have className on everything

Comment: I am still not sure I understand, but if you only want your style to affect certain `<p>`-elements, and not all, then yes, you need to add a class name

Comment: You might want to look into Styled Components though, then you can create your own version of p, as a styled react component. Then you don't need to use class name, but you can use your styled react component instead.

Answer (score 0):

The `p` tag will apply to *all* `p` elements on the page. Assuming you use classes:

You could do something like this, which styles the `p` tag directly:

```
style.css

.myClass {
    color: #fff;
}

mypage.html

<p class="myClass">This text is styled</p>
```

You could also do it so that any `p` elements *within* another tag (ie a `div`) are styled with this:

```
style.css

.myClass p {
    color: #fff
}

mypage.html

<div class="myClass">
    <p>This text will be styled</p>
</div>
```

If you want to style individual elements, you might like to use the `style` HTML attribute, you can do this:

```html
<p style="color: #eb4034>This text will be red</p>
```